# Create dynamic XML consists of n parts

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, dynamic, doctrine-1.2

I have to create an xml like this:

```
<Flow>
    <Invoice xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        /* more stuff */
    </Invoice>
    /*...*/
    <Invoice xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        /* more stuff */
    </Invoice>
</Flow>
```

Here is my situation:

```
//execute a query with doctrine
$clients = ClientTable::getInstance()->createQuery('c')
    ->addWhere('...stuff...')
    ->execute();

//for every client I have to save certain information about the database
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    /** @var $client Client */
    $values = array();
    $values['client_id'] = $client->id;
    $values['release_date'] = date("Y-m-d");
    //...stuff... 
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->create($values);
}
```

For each cycle of foreach tag must generate an tag `<Invoice>` to xml.

I would do something like this:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$flow = $xml->createElement('Flow');
$xml->appendChild($flow);
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    //...stuff... 
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->create($values);
    $invoiceXml = $invoice->createInvoiceXml();
    $flow->appendChild($invoiceXml);
}
$xml->save('flow.xml');
```

I tried my idea and I realized that inside the function `createInvoiceXml()` I have to instantiate a new object `DOMDocument()` which will create a new line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is this is wrong!
Then I realize that may not be the best way, then I ask you what?

---

### UPDATE

I thought of a new solution:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$flow = $xml->createElement('Flow');
$xml->appendChild($flow);
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    //...stuff... 
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->create($values);
    $invoiceXml = $invoice->createInvoiceXml($xml);
    $flow->appendChild($invoiceXml);
}
$xml->save('flow.xml');
```

and here is the function `createInvoiceXml()`

```
/**
 * @param $xml DOMDocument
 * @return DOMElement
 */
public function createInvoiceXml(&$xml)
{
    $inv = $xml->createElement('Invoice');
    $inv->setAttribute('xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation', 'schema.xsd');
    $inv->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

    $inv->appendChild($xml->createElement('foo'));
    //stuff
    return $inv;
}
```

What do you think? It is a good solution? With this solution, then I have no problem writing a unittest?

Comment: How come in createInvoiceXml() function you have to instantiate a new DOMDocument()?  Why not just a new DOMElement that you can append?

Comment: so you think I should pass `$xml` to function `createInvoiceXml()`

Comment: Your updated question looks good, I see nothing wrong with that if it works.  Just make sure to check that `$xml instanceof DOMDocument` before using it and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok! Then I'll do that Thanks!